A "cognitive fallacy" occurring when thinking something is obvious?
The other day a friend of mine was sharing some of his recent philosophical reflections and I caught myself mentally rolling my eyes thinking that this is completely obvious.
Then I thought to myself: Would I actually have thought of that myself, let alone formulated it verbally? Let's give people some slack!
A more extreme example is a post I read a long time ago about someone reading the teachings of Buddha, then shrugging them off saying "this is trivial and obvious, I could have thought of that". But could you really though? Why didn't you?
I feel that we sometimes get this kind of cognitive bias that after we hear and understand an explanation, we interpret it as easy but forget the vast difference between hearing a fact and discovering it ourselves.
My question is simply if this is a known "bias" in psychology, or if it has a name?

Possible duplicate of: Name of the psychological effect that make us see correlation that may not exist, What is the psychological explanation for the phenomena that a person sees the solution to a problem as “simple” once it has been found?, Why do solutions to problems feel simple (or obvious) once we are given them?
